# Initializing correlation set on direct bound receive

Tags: biztalk, correlation

I have a singleton orchestration which I want to process every message of type X coming into the messagebox. It doesn't matter where these messages are coming from (orchestrations or receive ports), but I want to ensure that the same orchestration instance processes all of them in the order they arrive in the messagebox.

Can I do this? I need to correlate the singleton receive shapes on something, but I am not sure what. Which properties can I use?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to implement this type of processing before.  Using ordered delivery along with correlating on a value for different types will work.  In my case I had a groupId that would get promoted into the context.  So all messages for groupId 0 would get process by a single orchestration in sequential order.

The Implementing FIFO processing with BizTalk Server 2006 article in [BizTalk HotRod](http://biztalkhotrod.com/Documents/Hotrod1Q32007%20Final.pdf) might help.

Comment: Thanks Derek. This answered my question. There actually is no problem doing what I need to do. The singleton orchestration subscription is created based on a combination of the correlation type being based on BTS.MessageType and the logical receive port message type. This acts in a similar way that a filter on a normal receive shape and results in a subscription being created to the correct message type when the orchestration is enlisted.